# Error while upgrading kernel headers on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kernel, linux-headers

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a 64-bit machine and trying to upgrade kernel headers from 4.10 to 4.11 following this: http://linuxg.net/install-kernel-4-11-on-ubuntu/. However, when I execute:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.11*.deb linux-image-4.11*.deb
```

I get the following error trace:

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.11.12-041112.
(Reading database ... 209165 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.11.12-041112_4.11.12-041112.201707210350_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.11.12-041112 (4.11.12-041112.201707210350) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.11.12-041112-generic.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.11.12-041112-generic_4.11.12-041112.201707210350_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.11.12-041112-generic (4.11.12-041112.201707210350) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.11.12-041112-lowlatency.
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-4.11.12-041112-lowlatency_4.11.12-041112.201707210350_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.11.12-041112-lowlatency (4.11.12-041112.201707210350) ...
dpkg: error processing archive linux-image-4.11*.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Setting up linux-headers-4.11.12-041112 (4.11.12-041112.201707210350) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.11.12-041112-generic (4.11.12-041112.201707210350) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.11.12-041112-lowlatency (4.11.12-041112.201707210350) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.11*.deb
```

Can anybody tell how to fix this?

Comment: It is unclear what  is your goal. Why are you trying to update only headers without the image? Headers without the kernel binary are useless.

Comment: I think linux-image package is not in the same folder you downloaded linux-headers. Check it

Comment: I'm trying to install a library and it requires that on 16.04 Ubuntu, I use the 4.11 version of kernel headers instead of 4.10 (which is what I am currently using). Is this not the way to go?